# How do i get this scoring system to work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a scoring system for the previous quiz game i asked about.

```py
score = 0

if guess == song_name:

    print("2 points")

    score = score + 2

elif 

    print("1 point")

    score = score + 1

else:

    guess != song_name

    print("0 points")

    score = score + 0
```

I want the player too be given 2 points when they get the answer right first time, 1 point when they get it right second attempt and 0 points if they don't get it right the second time.

Comment: `elif` requires a condition

Comment: `elif` needs a condition. `else` doesn't need a condition, your comparison does nothing. You also don't get any guesses from the user.

Comment: What would you suggest for the condition with the elif?

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for taking answer and attempt counter.

```
score = 0
attempt = 0
guess = ""
while guess != song_name:
    attempt += 1
    print("Enter answer")
    guess = input()
if attempt == 1:
    print("2 points")
    score = score + 2
elif attempt == 2:
    print("1 point")
    score = score + 1
else:
    guess != song_name
    print("0 points")
```